# c# xml -> dictionary <string, Tuple<string,string,string>> in Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

I have this XML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <data ID="1" Tag1="A" Tag2="123" Tag3="C" />
  <data ID="2" Tag1="AB" Tag2="12C3" Tag3="D" />
</Tag>
```

I want the convert the document into Dictionary Type `<string, Tuple<string,string,string>>`

So basically ID -> Tag1, Tag2, Tag3

I know there are a lot that do Key -> Value like this:

```
var configDictionary = xdoc.Descendants("data").ToDictionary(
            datum => datum.Attribute("ID").Value,
            datum => datum.Attribute("value").Value);
```

But i need have the value take in 3 strings.

Comment: So in the second lambda expression, create a `Tuple<string, string, string>` from the three attributes, instead of just a single string. What have you tried in terms of doing that, and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple. All you're missing is a declaration of the tuple using `Tuple.Create`:

```
var configDictionary = xdoc.Descendants("data")
             .ToDictionary(
                   datum => datum.Attribute("ID").Value,
                   datum => Tuple.Create(datum.Attribute("Tag1").Value,
                                         datum.Attribute("Tag2").Value,
                                         datum.Attribute("Tag3").Value));
```

Note this has no validation that the attributes actually exists, which will need to be added.